# Complement of a Regular Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Prove whether or not the complement of every regular graph is regular.

What I have:

It appears to be so from some of the pictures I have drawn, but I am not really sure how to prove that this is the case for all regular graphs. I am guessing that I should use induction, such as by showing that it is true for a 1-regular graph, and then, assuming that if it is true for an n-regular graph, then it is also true for an n+1-regular graph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Suppose vertex $v$ in $G$ has degree $d$. What will the degree of its complement be? Out of the $n-1$ other vertices in $G$, $v$ is adjacent to $d$ of them, and not adjacent to $n-1-d$ of them (if two vertices in a graph are connected by an edge, we say the vertices are adjacent). So the degree of $v$ in the complement of $G$ is $n-1-d$.

Now if $G$ is a regular graph, all of its vertices have the same degree, $d$, and so they all have degree $n-1-d$ in the complement of $G$.

Comment: if i take a graph $G$ with $4$ vertex which is $2$ reglar graph$(\text{basically a cycle })$,then its complement $G^{'}$ seems out to be $4-2-1=1$ regular graph though it is $2$ reglar graph.Why there is  such contradiction?

Comment: what contradiction?

Comment: the complement of $C_4$ is a $1$-regular graph, it is a matching.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a regular graph, that is there is some $r$ such that $|\delta_G(v)|=r$ for all $v\in V(G)$. Then, we have $|\delta_\bar{G}(v)|=n-r-1$, where $\bar{G}$ is the complement of $G$ and $n=|V(G)|$. Hence, the complement of $G$ is also regular.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly does $\delta$ stand for?

Comment: it means the degree of vertex $v$. The subindex tells you in which graph this degree is being taken. So $\delta_G(v)$ is the degree of $v$ in the graph $G$.