# Show that if $G$ and $G^c$ are $r$-regular graphs then the order of $G$ is odd.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Show that if $G$ and $G^c$ are $r$-regular graphs then the order of $G$ is odd.

I am not sure how approach this problem.

I know that $$\sum\deg v_i = 2E$$ and the sum of the degrees of $G$ is $rn$ which is the same as the sum of the degrees for $G^c$. Also each vertex is connected to $r$ other vertices and not connected to $r$ vertices. What am I missing?

Comment: When you write \text{deg} v_i instead of \deg v_i, then you see $\displaystyle\text{deg} v_i$ (without proper spacing) instead of $\displaystyle\deg v_i$.  Notice the spacing in $a\deg b$ and $a\deg(b)$ (coded as a\deg b and a\deg(b)), with more space to the right of $\deg$ in the former than in the latter. MathJax is based on the way of coding mathematical notation that is used in $\TeX$, which is sophisticated software, designed by no less than Donald Knuth. I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \in V(G)$. Then there are $r$ vertices connected to $v$ in $G$ and $r$ vertices not connected to $v$ in $G$. That is, there are 
$$ V(G) = 1 + 2r $$
vertices altogether. Hence $n = 1 + 2r$ is odd.

Comment: Of course... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked in the following link: [Complement of a Regular Graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236576/complement-of-a-regular-graph)

My answer is based on an answer given in the above link.

Suppose that $|V(G)| = n$, i.e., the order of $G$ is $n$, and suppose that $G$ and $G^{c}$ are both $r$-regular graphs, letting $G^{c}$ denote the complement of $G$.

Given a vertex $v$ in the vertex set of $G$, we have that $v$ is of degree $r$ in $G$.  It easily seen that the degree of $v$ in $G^{c}$ is $n-1-r$.

But since $G$ and $G^{c}$ are both $r$-regular graphs, we have that $$r = n-1-r$$ and we thus have that $$n = 2r+1$$ thus proving that the order of $G$ is odd.